# How Do I Switch Back To Sculpt Mode?

Tags: sculpting

I'm New To Blender, I selected something that brought me to *Object Mode*.
I went ahead and tried to switch back to sculpt mode, but it doesn't have any options for me except *Object Mode*.

How can I fix this? I haven't been able to work on my project due to his issue.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, the orange lines around the model means that you are probably selecting more than one object and one of those could be not compatible with sculpt mode (like a Camera), make sure to select your object only and it has to be highlighted in Yellow

Comment: make sure to select only "mesh objects" to be precise.